# Inserting into CollectionView throws Invalid Update Error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, collectionview

I am using the new Firebase and I'm making many calls to the database one after another to retrieve a certain object. In the callback, I added the object to my `CollectionView` datasource and then call `collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths`.

But I'm getting an invalid update error. I'm guessing this is because items are being retrieved so fast from the database that the last update hasn't completed before the next one starts. How can I fix this?

Also, I should `dispatch_async` to main thread inside the callback, right?

Comment: Did any of the following answers helped you?

Answer (score 0):

In a `UICollectionView`, the number of items returned by `numberOfItemsInSection:` must match the number of items being live updates in your block. To solve this discrepancy, what you should do is maintain an integer that counts the number of items to display in your collection view and return that, instead of yourArray.count. In addition, you should maintain this integer in `yourCollectionView.performBatchUpdates({})`

Answer (score 0):

Data source updates its item count first, then `performBatchUpdates` was called to update the `UICollectionView` and `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` returns the post-update item count, it confuses `collectionView.performBatchUpdates`.

Solution: add a property as the item count and update it inside performBatchUpdates closure

```
func updateItems(updates: [ItemUpdate]) {
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
      for update in updates {
          switch update {
         case .Add(let index):
              collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)])
              itemCount += 1
          case .Delete(let index):
              collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)])
              itemCount -= 1
          }
      }
  }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple if the problem is that your queries are called before the previous be completed.

You will put to every function with query a completion (except the last one) and then you will call them one by one.

Let's say that you have two queries queryOne and queryTwo.

```
func queryOne(completion: Result<Void> -> Void)  {

//Below the line that you complete the query 
//Usually after the for loop if you have
completion(.Success())

}

func queryTwo()  {


}
```

Now you have to synchronize them in your viewDidLoad

```
queryOne() { result in
            switch result {
            case .Success:
                self.locationManager.delegate = self
                queryTwo()

            case .Failure( _): break // Handle error
            }



        }
```